# error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<int>’ and ‘int’)

Tags: c++

I am trying to resolve  Fractional Knapsack problem (Maximum Value of the Loot), there is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;

double get_optimal_value(int capacity, vector<int> weights, vector<int> values) {
  double value = 0.0;
  vector<int> ratio;
  for(int i=0; i<values.size(); i++) {
      ratio.push_back(values[i]/weights[i]);
  }
  int a = 0;
  while(capacity>0){
      auto it = std::max_element(ratio.begin(), ratio.end());
      a = std::max(capacity, *it);
      capacity -= *it * a;
      values = values + a * *it;
  }
  return value;
}
```

And I get the following error :

> error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::vector’
> and ‘int’)

For the line :

```
values = values + a * *it;
```

Comment: What do you expect that line to do? You are adding a vector (values) to an integer (a * *it). That operation is not defined.

Comment: Thank you! I just confused value with values.

Comment: Are you confusing your double 'value' var for your vector 'values'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't that line be something like `value += a * (*it);`? That appears to be a typo to me. Probably, you have got confused between `value` and `values`. The latter one is a `std::vector<int>`. You surely cannot add a number(`double`) to a `vector` in it that way.

If you instead want to add `a * (*it)` to every value then probably a simple range-based for loop will work or something like [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). Or if you want to insert that element into the vector, then probably something like [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) would do the job for you.

Comment: Yet it is the case

Comment: @bipll I believe that's the case (confirmed by the OP). What you've suggested in comment to the other answer (and what that answer itself suggest) doesn't make any sense in a solution of fractional knapsack problem.

Comment: Which means the whole question is about a single-character type error.

Comment: @bipll I had raised the flag back then that the question is caused by a typo, they have marked it as helpful, but I don't think SO closes a question after it has an accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted to do

```
values.push_back(a * *it);
```

to append the result of `a * *it` to the `vector`.

Comment: Or `for(int &v: values) v += a * *it;` >_>